# How to make Windows 7 based Virtual machine running on Ubuntu 14.04 host machine detect a USB device?

Tags: 14.04

I have a medical device spirometer that connects via USB cable on a windows 7 machine and gets detected. It has a .exe file and corresponding 3 .dll files. Upon plugging the device into a windows machine and running the .exe file it detects the device perfectly,but when I am running windows 7 via virtual machine on Ubuntu 14.04 host machine and running the .exe file or trying to run the .exe file through wine on Linux the .exe file launches but showing "Device not connected" pop up window. Windows 7 running virtually on Linux platform is unable to detect the device.

Although, upon plugging in the device on a Linux machine and checking from the terminal using "lsusb" command I found it getting detected and displayed on the terminal screen.

Note: The manufacturer says they provide support for the device solely for windows machine and not on Linux platform.

Any suggestions as to how to get the device detected on the Linux platform would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please describe what you're using for virtualization. There are lots of programs for that, N0rbert wrote what to do on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle VM VirtualBox - then you should install VirtualBox Extension pack (on host), Guest Additions (on guest) and enable [USB Device Filters](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#usb-support) in the properties of virtual machine.

Steps:

1. Insert the device into host machine
2. Ensure that device is detected with `lsusb`
3. Change the settings of virtual machine to enable USB device filter - click on [image: add host device] to add device from host machine:

   [image: USB Device Filters]
4. Apply settings
5. Start the virtual machine

Comment: Upvoted. Also, make sure to install VirtualBox Extension Pack! There are devices that change their vid:pid ID, in that case, add those to the filter as well! I'm not sure it was available in 14.04's time though, so OP might need an upgrade, compile from source, or copy lots of packages with dependencies from a newer version.