# Map microcontrollers connected (FTDI) on physical USB port to Windows Virtual Machine in Virtualbox as COM

Tags: 18.04, usb, virtualbox, tty, serial-port

**Host OS:** Ubuntu 18.04

**Virturalized:** Windows 10

**Things I have already done:**

1. Added $USER to the dialout group and rebooted
2. sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB*
3. Mapped the port where my microcontroller gets detected as a Serial communication device to a COM4 port from the settings for the VM

[image: 18]

**Result:**

The Device Manager of the VM shows only COM1 and hence no success at  serial communication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Windows 7 based Virtual machine running on Ubuntu 14.04 host machine detect a USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124729/how-to-make-windows-7-based-virtual-machine-running-on-ubuntu-14-04-host-machine)

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks a lot... :) Also, the question is regarding detection of the USB device and not an FTDI one. I even got an error stating that the device won't work as expected but it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert)'s comment did guide in the right direction. I am leaving the answer here with the screenshots as a documentation so that others won't scratch their heads trying to do the setup using Serial port Settings of Virtualbox.

So, the steps are as follows:

1. Connect your microcontroller via USB.
2. Open the USB section in the Settings for your VM.
3. Add the intended device as per the screenshot (by clicking on 2nd icon in the right pane).

[image: USB settings in Virtualbox]

4. Power ON the VM and you will get this error which can be ignored.

[image: Warning message before the VM Boots]

5. Under Device Manager on your VM you will find your device

[image: Device showing on COM3 in VM]