# Start a Virtualbox VM with the webcam on

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, webcam

There are many questions and instructions out there about how to add a webcam to a VM, under Ubuntu host OS (in particular, with Win 10 guest OS, but this is likely irrelevant).

[How can I use my webcam with Ubuntu running in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4875/how-can-i-use-my-webcam-with-ubuntu-running-in-virtualbox/1237808#1237808)

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=87398

https://scribles.net/using-webcam-in-virtualbox-guest-os-on-windows-host/

I have found how to do that, and I posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237808/226614).
It requires as a last step to attach the webcam to the VM, via command line.
But for that command to be valid, the VM has to be running, otherwise an error pops

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm "Win10" webcam attach .1
VBoxManage: error: Machine 'Win10' is not currently running
```

[This other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/959600/226614) to the same question shows an alternative to the last step. With the VM running, go to *Devices* -> *Webcams* -> Tick the checkbox.

In any of the two cases, whenever the VM is shut down, and later restarted, the webcam starts detached, and the last step (either via CLI or VM menus) has to be manually performed.

**Is there any way to get the webcam on/attached by default?**

**EDIT**
As per comment, I am posting some more info.

1. Only the relevant lines of `lsusb` here.

```
    $ lsusb -t
    /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
        |__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

2. `VBoxManage`

```
    $ VBoxManage list webcams
    Video Input Devices: 2
    .1 "Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
    /dev/video0
    .2 "Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
    /dev/video1
```

3. With the VM running, *Devices* -> *Webcams* shows to identical items, *Integrated Camera: Integrated C*.

In all cases, I wouldn't know why it is showing two webcams.

Comment: The answer depends on interface of webcam. If it is USB - [create a filter for it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124731/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert - The comment opens a few questions: 1) How to tell the "interface of webcam"? 2) If it is USB, how to tell the appropriate USB Controller (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) and filter? 3) If not USB, what to do?

Comment: 1) If USB, it should appear in `lsusb -t` with *Class=Video*. 2) USB 2.0 or 3.0 will be good. 3) check it in virtualbox GUI - on launched VM in *Devices → Webcams* menu.

Comment: @N0rbert - Please see edited OP. With `lsusb` I see two webcams. With Devices -> Webcams I see the same two devices. So are they usb or not? And with these details, how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So you have two USB Cameras. To bind them to the VM you have to set USB filter for them.

At first install VirtualBox Extension pack (on host), Guest Additions (on guest) and enable [USB Device Filters](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#usb-support) in the properties of virtual machine.

Steps:

1. Change the settings of virtual machine to enable USB device filter - click on [image: add host device] to add device from host machine:

   [image: USB Device Filters]
2. Apply settings by pressing OK
3. Start the virtual machine